# How can I select 'Shipping' step on checkout page after updating product item from minicart

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

How can I select `Shipping` step on checkout page after updating product item from minicart?

when I am on Review & Payment step, at that time if I click on incremental of mini cart then page does a refresh & lands me back on 'Review & Payment' step, I want it to land on step 1 i.e. 'Shipping' step

[image]

Comment: `I need to set Shipping step ` means?...Do you want cursor to auto focus?

Comment: when I am on Review & Payment step, at that time if I click on incremental of mini cart then page does a refresh & lands me back on 'Review & Payment' step, I want it to land on step 1 i.e. 'Shipping' step

Comment: can you please show me your checkout screen?

Comment: I had added screenshot